# iOS: Adding a window without tableViews etc

Tags: ios, uiview

I"m having trouble finding out how to add a new window to an app that is not based on a table view, but is a single window based app (which now needs a window to enter a few settings). All the tutorials start with the table view template, so if anyone has any pointers, I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: iOS only has one window per application so I assume you mean a new view. Have a look at some tutorials that use a UIViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go look at the example code you found and look for the 'tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method. In here it'll show you how to push a new view. You'll probably want to do something similar so make sure your main view has a navigation controller setup and do something along these lines:

```
UIViewController *newViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

You can call these lines from a button tap or some other action on the visible view. This will create your next view controller and bring it to the front. If you're looking to do something modal (presented from the bottom of the view) then you'll want to use `presentModalViewController:animated` instead.

You may also want to look into a tabbed controller as this might suite your purposes well also.

Comment: So I add a Navigation Controller to the storyboard, and control-drag from that to my principal View. But this introduces a navigation item onto the screen, which I don't need to see. Hiding it in ViewDidLoad, however, hides the whole view on startup.

Comment: I also couldn't find the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in the Master/Detail template. I seem to be starting from the wrong place.

Comment: Okay, got it:  [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];